# How do I remove programs from my Lego Mindstorms EV3 project?

Tags: ev3, software

The title says it all. But to be more specific, I find it annoying that I have to download one single program to the EV3 Brick but then all the others in the project end up in the brick too, therefore I have to look in the EV3 storage to remove the specific programs I don't want. I bet there is a way to permanently delete certain programs from a project, but how??

Comment: Please clarify if you are using the old EV3 environment (with graphic blocks) or the new scratch based one...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve The block-based programming environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click the little wrench button, you can see your programs, images, sounds and more. You just have to click on the program you do not want and delete it. Alternatively, you can hide it.

[image]

Hope it helped.

Sorry my handwriting is terrible with a mouse.

Comment: I recall that most photo editors have a feature to add text, which would solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah but I used snip and sketch window app. Did it help you?